# (java/scala) MultiHashMap with mutable bucket?

Tags: java, scala, data-structures

I'm looking for a dictionary-type data structure which automatically adds the value I specify to the key's (already present) collection. So if I say put(k, v), I want get(k) to return v union v' where v' is the previous collection.

Is there such a data structure already present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap.addBinding`?

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Google's Guava library has [several implementations](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).